# How to calculate the final adjusted weights for a neural network model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-science-model

My understanding of a neural network algorithm is the 1st row/observation of the dataset is inputted into the NN model and then backpropagation happens to adjust the weights, until some condition is met and the weights stop adjusting. This then happens again on the 2nd row/observation of the dataset, 3rd row/observation of the dataset and so on. Say if the dataset has 1000 rows, then I will have 1000 weights. How would then the final weight be calculated for the entire NN model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how it works. There is a given number of weights given by the architecture you chose. Those weights are then updated on each iteration of the learning process. Depending on your method of learning, your weights may be updated once on 1000 observations, or for groups of observations (even groups of 1). May I suggest you to read an introduction to statistical learning http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ ? or to join  the machine learning course on coursera https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning ?

Comment: Ok will do, many thanks for your input and the links!